# Can't mount microSD card with Freenove ESP32 WROVER Module and Sparfun MicroSD module

Tags: esp32

I'm using Freenove's ESP32 WROVER Module with their GPIO expansion board as shown in the image below:

[image: Circuit image]

I'm trying to integrate Sparkfun's microSD module in the circuit. [Here's my sketch](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1isx64ksknl4cnr/esp32_microsd_module.ino?dl=0). However, I'm unable to mount the card despite it works fine using an ESP32-CAM board with integrated SD card reader.

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please do not post a link to code ... add the code text to your post ... use the edit button ... no pictures please

Answer (score 0):

Your pinout to the SD is unclear from the picture, but I can see that you are using **pin 15**, which is the MTDO strapping pin- which will cause issues for sure.
[image]

You can learn more here about using alternative pins here:
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-spi-communication-arduino/